# Select values with Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I have a table with this sample data, where `Id` and `productname` are columns. I need an output where it returns `Product1` when it has same Id along with other `ProductNames` (see the next table for the output).

| Id | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Product1 |
| ABC123 | Product2 |
| XYZ345 | Product1 |
| PQR123 | Product1 |
| MNP789 | Product3 |
| EFG456 | Product1 |
| EFG456 | Product6 |
| EFG456 | Product7 |
| JKL909 | Product8 |
| JKL909 | Product8 |
| JKL909 | Product8 |
| DBC778 | Product9 |
| DBC778 | Product10 |

Desired output:

| Id | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Product1 |
| ABC123 | Product2 |
| EFG456 | Product1 |
| EFG456 | Product6 |
| EFG456 | Product7 |

Basically it's grouped by Id when it has `Product1` with other products.

I tired following query but its not giving desired result

```
select Id, ProductName 
from tbl1 
group by Id, ProductName 
having count(ProductName) > 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Two typical options are:

```
select * from T t
where exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.Id = t.Id and t2.ProductName <> t.ProductName
);

with data as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by Id) as cnt
    from T
)
select * from data where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is one method to accomplish the task. The `DISTINCT` is not required with your sample data but is needed in case there are dups, which might be possible based on the sample data for other products.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, ProductName
FROM @Product
WHERE Id IN(
    SELECT Id
    FROM @Product
    WHERE ProductName = 'Product1'
    )
    AND Id IN(
    SELECT Id
    FROM @Product
    WHERE ProductName <> 'Product1'
    )
ORDER BY Id, ProductName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be better off grouping the table without the `having` statement. The query will be like the following:

```
select * 
from tbl1 
group by Id, ProductName
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id)` will give you the `HAVING`-like functionality.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Id,
           ProductName,
           NumProductsForId = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id),
           DoesIdContainDesiredProductName = MAX(CASE WHEN ProductName = 'Product1' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Id)
    FROM tbl1
)
SELECT Id, ProductName
FROM cte
WHERE NumProductsForId > 1
  AND DoesIdContainDesiredProductName = 1;
```